# Vim に bracey プラグインをインストールしたが、:Bracey コマンドを実行しても動作しない

Tags: vim

**現象**
VimのbraceyというLive Serverのようなプラグインをインストールした後に、Vimで`:Bracey`コマンドを実行してもブラウザが起動せずに、`E117: 未知の関数です: bracey#start`というエラーメッセージが表示された。

**期待値**
Vimで`:Bracey`コマンドを実行すると、ブラウザが立ち上がり製作中のHPを見られるようにしたい。

**再現手順**

1. `.vimrc`に下記の設定を書き込む。
2. その後、[vim-jp » Vimのユーザーと開発者を結ぶコミュニティサイト Linuxでのビルド方法](https://vim-jp.org/docs/build_linux.html)を参考に、Vimをビルドする。
3. Python3をBashで起動する。
4. Vimを起動し、:braceyコマンドを実行する。

以下、`.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

"設定
set number
set title
set showmatch
syntax on
set tabstop=4
set smartindent
set fenc=utf-8

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'turbio/bracey.vim', {'do': 'npm install --prefix server'}

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

**参考リンク**
[braceyのチュートリアル](https://github.com/turbio/bracey.vim/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、`~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` ディレクトリは存在しますか？ Vundle を使うにあたって、`.vimrc` の設定を追記するだけでは手順が足りません。

Comment: @cubick はい、存在します。

Comment: では `.vimrc` の編集後、Vim を起動して `:PluginInstall` は実行済みですか？

Comment: @cubick はい、実行済みです。

Comment: Vundle で指定した bracey 以外のプラグインは動作していますか？

Comment: @cubick はい、動作してます。

Comment: @cubick 諦めてVimを削除して`apt`で再インストールしました。

Answer (score 0):

braceyではなくBracey、先頭を大文字にしても同じでしょうか?

Comment: はい、先頭を大文字にしても同じです。